# React-absolute-grid plugin change state of dragEnabled but doesn't drag

Tags: reactjs

I have this component that I use from React-absolute-grid plugin
that enable me to render multiple views and to drag and change the sorting of the view:

```
  <AbsoluteGrid items={this.state.sampleItems}
                    displayObject={(<SampleDisplay />)}
                    onMove={onMoveDebounced}
                    dragEnabled={this.state.dragEnabled}
                    zoom={zoom}
                    responsive={true}
                    verticalMargin={42}
                    itemWidth={290}
                    itemHeight={290}/>
```

The comp has a dragEnabled prop, if it is true I can drag the views, if it is false I can't drag them.

I have a state dragEnabled that it's initial value is false, so I can't drag, and I have a button when I click it, it changes the state of dragEnabled to true so I can drag:

```
getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            dragEnabled: false
        };
    }


handleClick: function () {
    if ($("#editButton").html() === "Edit") {
        this.setState({
            dragEnabled: true
        });
        $("#editButton").html("Save");
        // this.forceUpdate();
    }
    else {
        this.setState({
            dragEnabled: false
        });
        $("#editButton").html("Edit");
        // this.forceUpdate();
    }
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

The problem is when I click the button it do really change the state to true but I don't have the ability to drag at all.